# Nesting Objects in Javascript - Anonymous is not a function error

Tags: javascript, oop, nested

Ok, so I'm a complete newbie to OOP in Javascript, apparently.  I thought I understood it, but it appears I only know a small portion.  Anyway, what I'm trying to do is setup an object to store and return data from an XML input by using a fairly simple string to retrieve data.  I'd like to retrieve the data with a string similar to `reader.getItem().getSubItem()` or something like that.

Below is an example of what I attempted, but I get the error `anonymous is not a function` each time I try to do a call to `fr.getType().isTexture()` so obviously, I need to change something.

```
//Create the object by passing an XML element containing sub-elements
var fr = new FeatureReader(test.child(i));

alert(fr.getName()); //returns the object's name
alert(fr.getType().isTexture()); //"anonymous is not a function" error

function FeatureReader(feature) {
    var feat = feature;
    this.getName = function() {
        return feat.name;
    };
    this.getType = new function() {
        this.isTexture = new function() {
            if (feat.type.texture == "yes") {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        };
        this.isModel = new function() {
            if (feat.type.model == "yes") {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        };
    };
}
```

Now, obviously I could just remove the surrounding `this.getType = function() {}` around the `this.isTexture` and `this.isModel` to get my data, but for the sake of learning something, I'd like to see how it is recommended that I set this object up to get the returned values using a string similar to what I mentioned in the first and second paragraphs.

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is simply assign an object instead of using `new`:

```
function FeatureReader(feature) {
    var feat = feature;
    this.getName = function() {
        return feat.name;
    };
    this.getType = {
        isTexture: function() {
            return feat.type.texture == "yes";
        },
        isModel: function() {
            return feat.type.model == "yes";
        }
    };
}
```

Then use the method like:

```
instance.getType.isTexture()
```

Note that you don't need to return `true` or `false`, as returning an expression that evaluates to boolean like `a == b`
 returns a boolean value.

Comment: Ahh, did not catch the == at first.  Very nicely done, and answers my question perfectly, and with less code than I was expecting!  Thank you very much!

Comment: You'll want to remove those semicolons in the internal object declaration

Comment: Yeah, I use Eclipse to write the initial code and it pointed that one out to me.  This is actually being used in Photoshop, but considering how unstable ESTK is, I've started writing my code in Eclipse first, then debugging in ESTK.  Thanks for pointing that out, though, others may have missed it.

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
    this.isTexture = new function() {
        if (feat.type.texture == "yes") {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
```

you're setting the "isTexture" property to the object constructed, not to that function. If you drop the `new` keyword from the statement, you'll be setting "isTexture" to be a function.

An expression of the form `new <some-function>` evaluates to an object, in other words.

*edit* — your "getType" property will *also* be an object, for the same reason. However, I think this would work:

```
alert( fr.getType.isTexture() );
```

Also note that your `if` statement can be simplified:

```
  return feat.type.texture == "yes";
```

Comment: Ok, but now I get `undefined is not an object` when attempting to access `isTexture()`

Comment: @DGolberg ah well "getType" will *also* be an object; I missed the function call in the alert calls.

Comment: @DGolberg I think you're complicating things a bit though, why not simply assign an object? See https://gist.github.com/elclanrs/8ef4012a4ea3f5b7213e

Comment: @elclanrs That does work nicely, but is there a way to do the if-statement-based conversion from string to boolean?  Also, could you make that an answer?  That's pretty much what I was looking for.